# passing specific expression in terraform

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I need to pass expression as tags.severity == "warning" but getting error as

```
│ Error: Missing newline after argument
```

i tried with this method but it is not working

```html
rules {
    is_basic = false
    expression    = "tags[\"severity\"] == warning"
    route_to_id   = escalation_policy.infra-warning.id
    route_to_type = "escalationpolicy"
  }
```

how to create this expression in terraform ?

Comment: Which resource is this?

Comment: resource is squadcast routing rules
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/SquadcastHub/squadcast/latest/docs/resources/routing_rules

Comment: What exactly is the problem in the second case?

Comment: i want the expresion as tags.severity == "warning"
but it is not working

Comment: Ok and what happens when you use the second code snippet? You said "it is not working". What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but how about this:

```
expression  =  "(tags.severity eq \"warning\")"
```

Comment: i tried with this expression it is not working